# ggsave gives blank jpeg image

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to save my plots in my R script. I used the following context:

```
dev.new()
matplot(cbind(y2,point_forecasted),type='l')
ggsave("model_data.jpg", path= "C:\\Users\\my_name")
dev.off()
```

However the saved image is just a white blank image! There is no plot.
I am not able to recognize the reason, could someone help me ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `ggsave` gives you freedom to choose the quality of jpeg. For example you can do the same thing by `ggplot(data, aes(x,y))+geom_line()` and then `ggsave("filename.jpeg",dpi=1080, width=50, units='cm')` and modify as needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ggsave` is designed for saving `ggplot2` graphics which use the `grid` graphics system. `matplot` uses the `base` graphics system and plots are saved in a different way.

You can open a jpeg device directly to save base graphics:

```
jpeg(filename="C:\\Users\\my_name\\model_data.jpg")
matplot(cbind(y2,point_forecasted),type='l')
dev.off()
```

Comment: In fact I would like to save my plots as .eps files, is that possible in R  ?

Comment: Yes, use the `postscript` device.